# Find and display surrounded text and highlight search term MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

What I need is to return the string search term (searchString) hightlighted and the previous 10 words and the next 10 (for example) words. I don't want to display all the content. I supposed I have to use indexOf or RegExp.

(I have try this until now and I managed to display all the content and hightlight the search term inside.)

Controller:

```
var result = (from c in db.sitecontent
                        where c.ContentText.Contains(searchString)
                        orderby c.ContentID
                        select new
                        {
                            ContentText = c.ContentText
                        }).ToString();


ViewData["searchTerm"] = searchString;

var mres= result.IndexOf(searchString) + 20;
var finalr= result.Substring(mres, result.IndexOf(searchString) + mres);
ViewData["searchR"] = finalr;
return View(result);
```

View:

```
@Html.Raw((ViewData["searchR"].ToString().Replace((string)ViewData["searchTerm"], "<span style='color:red'>" + (string)ViewData["searchTerm"] + "</span>")))
```

thank you

Comment: "Next 10 words" is a precise limit? Did you mean, "any amount of words up to 10" or something else?

Comment: no its not a limit. It could be 20 or 5. It doesnt matter.

Comment: "I don't want to display all the content" makes me guess the exact amount of words you want to display does matter.

Comment: I mean that I have a field for the content text. It is a big paragraph. What I need is to select the surrounded text. Yes lets say the 10 before and the 10 after. And between them the `searchString` hightlighted. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't check all the steps, but first, you have a problem when you compute your substring.

- For the start index you must ensure you actually can pick the 10
  chars before.
- For the total length you take, you'll also have to    check your
  string is large enough.

Here is the utility method to compute this.

```cs
public static string GetPreview(string searchString, int previewLength, string paragraph)
{
    var searchedStringLength = searchString.Length;
    var searchedStringPosition = paragraph.IndexOf(searchString);

    // Index from where you start your substring
    //  - In nominal case : index of your searched string - your length for preview
    //                  That is : searchedWordPosition - previewLength
    //  - If your string starts with your searched word, then index must be 0 and not previewLength
    //  - If your string has less than preview characters before your searched word then it must be a 0 index as well
    var leftPartLength = Math.Min(previewLength, searchedStringPosition);
    var startIndex = searchedStringPosition - leftPartLength;

    // Then you need to know how many characters you'll take from your starting point
    // You'll obviously take all from left index to searchedWordPosition : leftIndex + paragraph.Length
    // Then you need to pick maxmimum previewLength characters if possible
    // Otherwise, you'll pick what's left from the end of your searched word to the end of the string, 
    // that is your total string length -  searched word length - index of your seach word
    // To summarize. If your string is shorter than you think (5 chars only after your searched word)
    //      you'll get remaining chars that is : paragraph.Length - leftIndex - searchString.Length
    // But if your string is larger, simply pick 10 + your searchstring length :)

    // Total length is : left part length + word length + right part left
    var rightPartLength = Math.Min(previewLength, paragraph.Length - (searchedStringPosition + searchedStringLength));
    var length = leftPartLength + searchedStringLength + rightPartLength;

    // So your substring for preview is :
    var preview = paragraph.Substring(startIndex, length);

    return preview;
}
```

I tested it with automated tests it seems fine.
For your specific case, to get the results, call ToList() on your linq query (not to string). It gives you all the results.
Loop on those results similarly to below example.

```cs
var searchString = "amet";
var content = new[]
{
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer mollis eros at ligula ultricies consequat. Quisque consequat at quam sed gravida. Fusce dapibus nisi a ex mollis, in hendrerit massa tincidunt. Quisque a dictum nisi, vitae bibendum quam. Pellentesque vitae dui a quam condimentum cursus. Mauris id interdum lorem, eu congue ligula. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Praesent lobortis cursus nulla, vitae vehicula velit pretium sed. Maecenas nisl tellus, gravida pharetra justo nec, ultrices tempus mi.",
    "Ut id lectus dapibus, commodo mauris in, consectetur magna. Phasellus porttitor nisl malesuada quam pulvinar, sed eleifend eros tristique. Proin id magna eros. Morbi iaculis mattis magna nec pellentesque. Donec lacinia aliquam nibh, vel accumsan erat pharetra eget. Proin ut est accumsan, fringilla ex et, congue arcu. Nulla iaculis non lectus condimentum dictum.",
    "In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer at quam maximus, consectetur lectus sed, consequat nunc. Morbi ultrices nisi vel porttitor lobortis. Vestibulum rutrum dignissim purus, sit amet semper libero egestas in. Pellentesque sodales augue et commodo porta. Nullam eu mattis tortor. Aenean scelerisque pretium mi, ullamcorper malesuada metus gravida sed. Morbi rhoncus tincidunt hendrerit. Suspendisse ac sollicitudin nisl. Curabitur congue faucibus lacinia. Donec felis lectus, luctus id nunc non, efficitur tincidunt orci. Donec turpis massa, ultrices sit amet ex nec, laoreet scelerisque metus. Quisque id neque ac leo volutpat maximus in at erat. Nunc commodo, sapien sit amet elementum ullamcorper, justo velit condimentum dui, at condimentum eros eros vel enim. Maecenas gravida dui vel sem gravida auctor.",
    "Ut quam ligula, pellentesque nec placerat vel, scelerisque finibus nibh. Donec eu felis a felis gravida auctor. Mauris sollicitudin aliquam tellus. Praesent ac neque lacus. Donec quis sagittis nisl. Nunc at mauris dolor. Donec sagittis, erat sit amet elementum bibendum, lorem mauris vestibulum odio, id egestas risus ante vel tortor. Donec sit amet rhoncus velit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.",
    "Maecenas vehicula luctus neque vel pretium. Proin lacinia nec lectus eget faucibus. Maecenas tristique elementum consequat. Nunc convallis nibh lorem, non porttitor tellus maximus a. Ut tristique neque ac lorem pulvinar maximus. Nulla id odio nec libero facilisis feugiat. Aenean sed elit vel sem luctus rhoncus ut non lorem. Vivamus eu imperdiet arcu. Cras tempor sapien eget nunc ullamcorper efficitur. Curabitur eget blandit ligula, euismod mollis metus. Vestibulum interdum, purus sit amet porttitor semper, leo dolor feugiat libero, sed luctus diam ex non mauris. Curabitur a efficitur sapien. Quisque et gravida magna. Proin ut condimentum neque, nec sodales arcu. Nulla vitae cursus purus. Ut id enim sapien."
};

// Query (modified due to different data source here)
var query = (from c in content
            where c.Contains(searchString)
            select new
            {
                ContentText = c
            });

// Size of the preview
var previewLength = 10;

// Get all the results
foreach (var contentText in query.ToList())
{
    var paragraph = contentText.ContentText;
    Console.WriteLine(GetPreview(searchString, previewLength, paragraph));
}
```

Comment: Hello thank you for your reply.You get the point of what i need,and i try to adapt your code.The difference between my code and yours is that i have a Linq query to return my result, not a simple string, as the example since that i have had to convert my query to a string. It also does not recognize the min method. As a conclusion it returns the sql query instead of the content text. Any Ideas? Thanks alot

Comment: Hi :) My bad, it's Math.Min if i'm not mistaken. 
(see [MSDN Math class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.math(v=vs.110).aspx))
I'll update my answer this evening. 

For your Linq issue, it's due to differed execution.
You'll have to iterate through the results of your query.
[Linq Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries)

Try to apply this, and let me know :)

Comment: hello! ok I change to Math.Min. Another problem is that I get the message: `'IQueryable<SiteContent>' does not contain a definition for 'Length' and no extension method 'Length' accepting a first argument of type 'IQueryable<SiteContent>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` at the line `var searchedWordPosition = paragraph.IndexOf(searchString);` and at `var length = Math.Min(paragraph.Length - leftIndex - searchString.Length, searchString.Length + previewLength);` so I change to `Math.Min(paragraph.toString().Length.....` but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Amouerta Hi :) Sorry for being so late, i was into other stuff :p
You could have used my example with very minor rework. 
Here is a complete rework.
Beware i modified you linq query (it was good but not fitting to my example).

Comment: I get the error `SiteContent' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Contains<string>(IQueryable<string>, string)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable<string>` when I change to fit my data. thank you

Comment: Of course. Keep your linq query but don't call to string on it. I could not have exactly the same as i don't have your db object. But should i really explain that ? 
`(from c in db.sitecontent
                        where c.ContentText.Contains(searchString)
                        orderby c.ContentID
                        select new
                        {
                            ContentText = c.ContentText
                        })`

Comment: ok I did like this `var query = db.sitecontent.Where(d => d.ContentText.Contains(searchString))` because I get still this error  can you help me on what do I have to return? Do I have to store my final data to a ViewData and then to pass it to the View

Comment: Ok I found it out! Thank you